# jetty websocket asynchronous send from different sessions in java

Tags: java, session, asynchronous, websocket, jetty

I am using jetty websocket implementation and connecting to my jetty server from multiple clients. I use `session.getAsyncRemote.sendText()` to send messages to clients. Are the messages sent from a common queue for all the sessions or is there a separate sending queue for different sessions?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to connect from 2 different sessions and they do not seem to affect each other. I think sessions have their own queues.